# Computer regularly sends clones back to Earth after apocalypse

Tags: story-identification, books

A computer on the moon clones sets of the original inhabitants who escaped Earth's dying days. Millions of years go by where the computer keeps sending clones back to check on Earth's survival.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question is very terse and would be greatly improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Reminds me of the film Oblivion (which was apparently based on a graphic novel), but there are at least a couple things that don't match.

Comment: I recall an episodic novel about succeeding generations of clones who restore the human race on earth after every apocalyptic event. The ending takes place in the far future, when humanity has turned the moon base into a museum, believing that civilization has become proof against apocalypse. Then, humanity's interstellar civilization suddenly begins to vanish, leaving the clone moon base to start yet again. Does this sound familiar? I have not yet identified this novel.